# How to make symbol take up no document space in XML

Tags: xml, pdf

Is there a way to make a symbol take up no document space in XML but still appear in the document. For example, I want to have the '^' in my document for change tracking purposes, but I don't want it to disrupt the flow of the document. The reason for this is because I will be converting the XML to a PDF with some third party software and I don't want the symbol to take up room in the PDF. It should look something like this:

[image]

Notice how the symbol takes up no horizontal space and doesn't disrupt the flow of the document. Is it possible to do something in my XML to make this work?

Comment: XML is a data format and has nothing to do with _presentation_.  Presentation is a function of whatever program reads the XML and renders it into a viewable format.  Therefore, the question is not about XML but about the 3rd party code that is going to convert your XML to PDF, or render it to HTML, or any other display format.  Since you haven't told us what the 3rd party software is there is no way to answer the question.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Actually, I think your comment answers the question quite well and should be copied into an answer.

Comment: If the OP clarifies the question, an answer might be possible. I'll leave it as a comment for now.

Comment: We are working with Quark publishing to publish the XML as a PDF. Being that we don't have direct access to their code that does this process, I wasn't sure if there was something XML related I could do to fix this, but it sounds as though we will have to work with them on this.

Comment: Yes. If what you want is possible it will be some type of custom tag or attribute specific to the XML->PDF software.